# Completing a tab delimited file, by copying down the first string

Tags: linux, sed, command-line-interface, tr

I wasn't sure how to put this one into words. I have a list that I am trying to convert into a tab delimited file. Here is the list in raw form:

```
|01BFRUITS|
^banana
^apple
^orange
^pear
|01AELECTRONICS|
^television
^radio
^dishwasher
^computer
|01AANIMAL|
^bear
^cat
^dog
^elephant
|01ASHAPE|
^circle
^square
^diamond
^star
```

After much headaches I learned the GNU has sed -z (cat test.txt | sed -z 's/|\r\n^/\t/g' | tr '^' '\t' | tr  -d '|') which allowed me to create the following output

```
01BFRUITS       banana
        apple
        orange
        pear
01AELECTRONICS  television
        radio
        dishwasher
        computer
01AANIMAL       bear
        cat
        dog
        elephant
01ASHAPE        circle
        square
        diamond
        star
```

Now i'm trying to get the output to look like:

```
01BFRUITS       banana
01BFRUITS        apple
01BFRUITS        orange
01BFRUITS        pear
01AELECTRONICS  television
01AELECTRONICS        radio
01AELECTRONICS        dishwasher
01AELECTRONICS        computer
01AANIMAL       bear
01AANIMAL        cat
01AANIMAL        dog
01AANIMAL        elephant
01ASHAPE        circle
01ASHAPE        square
01ASHAPE        diamond
01ASHAPE        star
```

What type of command can handle that?

As suggested:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '/^\|/{ c1=$0; gsub(/\|/,"",c1) } /^\^/{ c2=$0; sub(/^\^/,"",c2); print c1,c2 }'  < test.txt
01BFRUITbanana
01BFRUITapple
01BFRUITorange
01BFRUITpear
01AELECTtelevision
01AELECTradioS
01AELECTdishwasher
01AELECTcomputer
01AANIMAbear
01AANIMAcat
01AANIMAdog
01AANIMAelephant
01ASHAPEcircle
01ASHAPEsquare
01ASHAPEdiamond
01ASHAPEstar
```

clipping the first string and ignoring the tab in between. This seems like a good start. I will try to see if i can fix this.

Resolved this by adding OFS to the print:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '/^\|/{ c1=$0; gsub(/\|/,"",c1) } /^\^/{ c2=$0; sub(/^\^/,"",c2); print c1,OFS,c2 }' < test.txt

01BFRUITS               banana
01BFRUITS               apple
01BFRUITS               orange
01BFRUITS               pear
01AELECTRONICS          television
01AELECTRONICS          radio
01AELECTRONICS          dishwasher
01AELECTRONICS          computer
01AANIMAL               bear
01AANIMAL               cat
01AANIMAL               dog
01AANIMAL               elephant
01ASHAPE                circle
01ASHAPE                square
01ASHAPE                diamond
01ASHAPE                star
```

Thanks for getting me there @jhnc

Edit:

Added  | sed -z s/\r\t\t//g to remove the \r\t after c1

```
cat test.txt | awk -v OFS='\t' '/^\|/{ c1=$0; gsub(/\|/,"",c1) } /^\^/{ c2=$0; sub(/^\^/,"",c2); print c1,OFS,c2 }' | sed -z s/\\r\\t\\t//g
01BFRUITS       banana
01BFRUITS       apple
01BFRUITS       orange
01BFRUITS       pear
01AELECTRONICS  television
01AELECTRONICS  radio
01AELECTRONICS  dishwasher
01AELECTRONICS  computer
01AANIMAL       bear
01AANIMAL       cat
01AANIMAL       dog
01AANIMAL       elephant
01ASHAPE        circle
01ASHAPE        square
01ASHAPE        diamond
01ASHAPE        star
```

Comment: `sed -ne '/^|.*|$/{;h;d;}; /^\^/{;G;s/.\(.*\)\n.\(.*\)./\2\t\1/p;}'`

Comment: `awk -v OFS='\t' '/^\|/{ c1=$0; gsub(/\|/,"",c1) } /^\^/{ c2=$0; sub(/^\^/,"",c2); print c1,c2 }'`

Comment: I input the file name into awk -v OFS='\t' '/^\|/{ c1=$0; gsub(/\|/,"",c1) } /^\^/{ c2=$0; sub(/^\^/,"",c2); print c1,c2 }' and it almost produced the desired results.  missing the tab

Comment: When I run the `awk` command shown in the question I get output similar to the expected output with the second column nicely aligned. (Depending on the length of the first column the indentation may be different.) You could also try `print c1 "\t" c2` and omit the `-v OFS='\t'`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F'|' -v OFS="\t" 'NF==3{h=$2; next}{gsub(/^[\^]/,""); print h,$0}' inputfile
01BFRUITS       banana
01BFRUITS       apple
01BFRUITS       orange
01BFRUITS       pear
01AELECTRONICS  television
01AELECTRONICS  radio
01AELECTRONICS  dishwasher
01AELECTRONICS  computer
01AANIMAL       bear
01AANIMAL       cat
01AANIMAL       dog
01AANIMAL       elephant
01ASHAPE        circle
01ASHAPE        square
01ASHAPE        diamond
01ASHAPE        star
```

**Or**

```
$ awk -F'[|^]' -v OFS="\t" 'NF==3{h=$2;next}{print h,$2}' inputfile
```

**Or**

```
$ awk -F'[|^]' 'NF==3{h=$2;next}{$0=h"\t"$2}1' inputfie
```

Comment: This worked nice.. and all in awk! This was a good learning experience!

Comment: nice way to handle the `\r` which I forgot about

Answer (score 0):

@jhnc

the print section of the command was missing OFS.. i added it and voila!

EDIT: To account for the \r\t after c1, i've added

```
| sed -z s/\\r\\t\\t//g
```

which resulted in

```
cat TESTCOUNT.txt | awk -v OFS='\t' '/^\|/{ c1=$0; gsub(/\|/,"",c1) } /^\^/{ c2=$0; sub(/^\^/,"",c2); print c1,OFS,c2 }' | sed -z s/\\r\\t\\t//g

01BFRUITS       banana
01BFRUITS       apple
01BFRUITS       orange
01BFRUITS       pear
01AELECTRONICS  television
01AELECTRONICS  radio
01AELECTRONICS  dishwasher
01AELECTRONICS  computer
01AANIMAL       bear
01AANIMAL       cat
01AANIMAL       dog
01AANIMAL       elephant
01ASHAPE        circle
01ASHAPE        square
01ASHAPE        diamond
01ASHAPE        star
```

Comment: You don't need nonstandard sed `-z` option for this. You could remove the `\r` without sed by just changing the gsub to `gsub(/[|\r],"",c1)` in original code

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En 'N;/^(\|(.*)\|)\n\^(.*)/{s//\2\t\3\n\1/;P};D' file
```

Append the following line.

If the first of the now two lines begins and ends with `|` and the first character of the second line begins `^`, format them as required, append the original first line and then print the amended first line only.

Whatever the result, delete the first line and repeat.